# Receive signal SIGTRAP when my text file contain characters over the limit

Tags: c

I am new to C and I can't fix this problem. When I write on the text file more than 27 characters I receive signal SIGTRAP. Trace/breakpoint trap.
I compile with Dev-C++ on Internet cafe computer windows 7. Text file contein: `Dinosaurs are a diverse group of animals of the clade Dinosauria`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
   FILE *myinput; 
   char **arr, **temp;
   char string[50];
   int i,j,wrd;

   arr=NULL;
   temp=NULL;
   i=0;
   myinput = fopen("word.txt", "r");
   while(1)
   {
     wrd = fscanf(myinput, "%s",string);
     if(!(wrd>0))
     {
       break;
     }
     temp=(char **)realloc(arr,i+1);
     arr=temp;
     arr[i]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(string)+1));
     strcpy(arr[i],string);
     i++; //counting words in a line from txt file.
   }
   for(j=0;j<i; j++)
   {
    printf("%s ", arr[j]);
   }
   free(arr);
return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You realloc() function has an incorrect parameter: size. You should be allocating a size of a pointer times the number i, but you allocate only i.

```
temp=(char **)realloc(arr, sizeof( char* ) * (i+1) );
```

The only problem remaining could be that you didn't include necessary headers.

Comment: @user3623727 I had a typo, missing brackets. Multiplication has precedence over addition.